# how my automation flow will be if google account login account is blocked for selenium(automation)?

Tags: selenium, google-search-console

as I can see Google has blocked login to google accounts with any automation tool.
So, what should be the authentication flow for the google services to login into the Google search console by automation tool or we can't access any google services with any automation tool.

Q1: Is there any OAuth flow for automation?

Q2: Is there any API for deleting the temporary URL from the "**google search console**"?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the chrome driver, relace it with this. This tells the chrome driver to point to a specific local host.

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

Then in the command prompt put this in

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="PUT HERE THE FILE DIRECTORY WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE ALL THE PERSONAL DATA"
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser,
Can you let me know how debug it with mac

Comment: I am sorry, I have never used mac os before

Comment: Can you share the command for the Linux environment as well